# Make ./gradlew build generate only shadowJar's jar file

Tags: java, gradle, shadowjar

When i do `./gradlew build`, it generate 2 jar files in `build\libs\`

- projectName.jar
- projectName-all.jar

the normal `./gradlew build`'s generated jar file, and the shadowJar's one ( it's the one with "-all").
Since only the shadowJar's jar work, how can i make so it keep only the shadowjar's jar file  and also remove the `-all` at the end ?

Here is my build.gradle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:2.0.1'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.9'
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "6.1.0"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


mainClassName = 'com.morialog.moriamines.Executor'
archivesBaseName = 'MoriaMines'

shadowJar {
    mergeServiceFiles()
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': mainClassName
    }
}

javafx {
    version = "13"
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}
```